# javascript parentnode.id not working the way i expected

Tags: javascript, html, parent-node

Right now I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function delete_box(n) {
     document.getElementById("box"+n).style.display = "none";
   }
<script>

<div id="box1">
 <table>
  <td>some code</td><td><input type="button" value="Delete this box" onclick="delete_box(1)"></td>
 </table>
</div>
```

It works fine. When I press the button the box disappears. However I want to simplify and have it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function delete_box(n) {
     document.getElementById(n).style.display = "none";
   }
<script>

<div id="box1">
 <table>
  <td>some code</td><td><input type="button" value="Delete this box" onclick="delete_box(this.parentnode.id)"></td>
 </table>
</div>
```

However it wont work as intended. The console says that the id is null and I'm not sure why. What have I done wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: The property name is [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode), not parentnode.

Comment: You don't need to find the id just to pass it to a function that looks it up: you can pass an element directly. (Also, the function just hides the box; it doesn't delete it.)

Comment: How do i do that? Sorry, i have no idea.

Comment: `hideBox(this.parentNode);` for instance

Comment: hideBox is already a defined function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, the property name is `.parentNode`. Also, you are referring to the wrong ancestor as you have an invalid html structure (browser has corrected it as you can see in the html inspector), so using you approach you should have written something like this :

```
delete_box(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id)
```

An explanation is as follows: `this` is linking to the `input` element, as you go further up with the `.parentNode` you get `td` -> `tr` -> `tbody` -> `table` -> `div#box1`.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ycdzqkk/1/)

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know you had to take into account the tbody even if it was not present in the code.

Comment: this way of traversing the DOM is brittle. How do I keep traversing until parentNode matches the following conditions - class contains 'cool' AND id is like 'item-<any text here>' ?

Answer (score 0):

First your HTML is invalid. A `td` lives inside of a `tr`, a `tr` lives inside a `thead`, `tbody`, or `tfoot` element. That element lives inside of a `table`.

The parent of the button would be a `td` not the `table`. You would have to look at multiple parents to get the id.